# introducing pointers to a large software project

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a fairly large software project written in `c++`.

In there, there is a `class foo` which represents a structure (by which i don't mean the programmers struct) in which `foo`-objects can be part of a `foo`-object.

Here's `class foo` in simplest form:

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
    public:
        void addFooIndex(unsigned int);
        unsigned int getFooIndex(unsigned int);
};
```

Every `foo`-object is currently stored in an object of `class bar`.

```
class Bar
{
    private:
        std::vector<Foo> foos;
    public:
        void addFoo(Foo);
        std::vector<Foo> getFoos();
}
```

So if a `foo`-object should represent a structure with a "inner" foo-object, I currently do

```
Foo foo;
Foo innerFoo;
foo.addFooIndex(bar.getFoos().size() - 1);
bar.addFoo(innerFoo);
```

And to get it, I obviously use:

```
Foo foo;
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < foo.getFooIndices().size(); ++i )
{
    Foo inner_foo;
    assert( foo.getFooIndices().at(i) < bar.getFoos().size() );
    inner_foo = bar.getFoos().at(foo.getFooIndices().at(i));
}
```

So this is not a problem. It just works. But it's not the most elegant solution.

I now want to make the inner `foo`s to be "more connected" with the `foo`-object. It would be obviously to change `class foo` to:

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        std::vector<Foo*> foo_pointers;
    public:
        void addFooPointer(Foo*);
        std::vector<Foo*> getFooPointers();
};
```

So now, for my question: How to gently change this basic class without messing up the whole code? Is there a "clean way"?

Comment: Are you actually copying `Foo` when you take it in and out of `Bar` as the code suggests? Right now `addFoo` will make a a copy, and the complete collection will be copied to create the return value of `getFoos()`. That would be rather unusual, so I'm wondering if thats actually whats going on.

Comment: actually, right now it's copies that I store, but that's just a small design mistake ;-)

Comment: Your interface is simply wrong – you shouldn’t bleed implementation details all over the place: `getFoos` is almost certainly a bad idea; the client of `Bar` has no business directly accessing this collection (also, you are returning a copy – is that intentional?)

Comment: Actually, in a previous version, this was all not only just working, but necessary. It's just like that for the sake of simplicity

Comment: The assert() in your for-loop is unneccessary, at() method already does bounds checking.

Comment: I would avoid using pointers in interface, use references. This is a general statement, not just to help the redactor.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this.

It all boils down to what kind of memory management you want/need. You can either store pointers in Foo, or Foo objects. Since you said you do not need `bar`, which currently 'owns' the Foo's memory-wise, I suggest you put them directly in Foo:

```
class foo
{
public:
  add_child(foo child); //Foo by value. Utilize 'move' semantics if copy is not possible.
  const std::vector<foo>& get_children(); //Get a reference to the children. Could use iterators or whatever.

private:
  std::vector<foo> foos;
}
```

Usage:

```
foo parent;
foo child;
foo grand_child;
child.add_child(std::move(grand_child)); //move semantics.
parent.add_child(child);  //no move semantics.

parent.traverse(root);

void traverse(foo root)
{
    root.discombobulate_the_parafunctors(); //act on root

    auto children = root.get_children();        
    std::for_each(children.begin(), children.end(), traverse);
}
```

This is what I would try to move towards, but you said you want to do it 'gently' - I guess you mean incrementally, without breaking things? Since ownership is transferred from bar to foo in the example above, it will not be possible to use both at the same time. The pointer approach, however, can be layered on top of the existing bar implementation.

If I really wanted to 'gently' switch, I'd make a class called something like foo_tree_view, which is like your first approach, with pointers, and doesn't assume ownership. I'd build it from a given `bar` instance, and then use it in client code.

```
std::vector<foo_tree_view> bar_view;

class foo_tree_view
{
public:
  foo_tree_view(foo this_foo, bar source);
  std::vector<foo*> get_children();
private:
   ...
}
```

At this point, you start gently changing all places to use this new foo_tree_view class. When all code uses it, you change to implementation of foo_tree_view to use the above implementation, without 'bar', and rename it to foo.

Hope you'll make some sense out of this answer!

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do:

1. Add a member variable `Bar * bar` and `int index` to Foo.
2. Have `Bar::addFoo` set `foo->bar = this` and `foo->index = foo.size()`
3. Implement `Foo:getFoo` on `Foo` to use the `getFooIndex` and `bar` to return a foo pointer
4. Implement `Foo:addFoo` similiarily

Then you should be able to use both APIs simultaneously. You can deprecate the index based apis and slowly remove them.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think having the `foo` object be responsible for its index in a container is a good idea. It should be blissfully unaware of the container(s) it is in. Maintaining these indices is the job of the container (if it is applicable for that container).

Your current code requires a `foo` to retrieve the inner `foo`s from `bar` so why not just retrieve them directly from `foo`?

```
for (unsigned int index = 0; index < foo.getFooPointers().size(); ++index)
{
    Foo* inner_foo = foo.getFooPointers().at(index);
}
```

Why do you need the inner `foo`s stored in `bar`? If there is some situation where you want to loop through all `foo`s, including inner ones, you could create an [iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator).

As a side note I would probably call the member function something like `getInnerFoos()` or `getChildren()` instead of `getFooPointers()`. The signature already tells you that it returns pointers of type `foo`.

Comment: Basically I don't need the `foo`s in the `bar`s. this was the work-around. The given method names are just symbolic and do not actually show what I'm doing ;-) I think you missed the question a bit: I know that pointers are better. I want to migrate to this, but I can't think of an elegant method to do so

Comment: I would probably deprecate the index management methods, add comments to them advising of the alternatives and educate the team on how to use `getFooPointers()` and any other new methods or objects you provide like maybe an iterator. Initially this could be done in an email to the team and then during code reviews it could be enforced.